# Read PHP files as text, extract variable values

Tags: php, regex, file, text

I am in a need to go through php files in a folder, i.e list all php files in that folder, read contents of each file, check whether few predefined variable names are present in code, if present read their values.

For example say a particular php file contains following variables.

```
$value1 = 'value of one';
$value2 = 'value of two';
```

Then my script should be capable of reading content of that file, extract values of $value1 and $value2.

Is there any simpler way to do that.

Really a great help if you can suggest a solution and that will be highly appreciated.

I think regex helps but I dont understand how to build the expression to match a variable name in code. So far I dont have code with me, If I clarify further i m looking a regex or similar solution to match/search pattern similar to a variable name, varibale name is known in advanced.

assumed search variable is found, then for extraction of variable value 'assigned in code' , the possible solution I see is string manipulation, i meant replacing content of line containing variable other than the variable value with empty strings. Apart form that is there a way to get the value.

Suppose in code,

so regex or other solution is search for string "$value1" & "$value2"

then it should be possible read out 'value of one' & 'value of two' as values of respective variables detected in code string.

Comment: what's in those files and why are those variables so important?

Comment: It is a custom mini cms used by one of my clients. He has many content pages as php files, certain content is defined as variable values there. Now he needs me to implement a search mechanism in frond end, have a  crawler cron job which iterates through files and read content. Its true that what he have is not a perfect solution, but in this case I have to do what he wants.

Comment: What about using the method I proposed once while adding the content to a database, then search from there?

Comment: unfortunately client is not giving me access to his CMS or database, I do only have to do search generated content php files. :)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do it `require` or `include` the files and compare the [`$GLOBALS`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php)-array values before and after. Of course this will not work if included files contain other code that executes right away.

Comment: Thanks. But in this case, there may be so many files to be inspected, so incuding all of them do have practical issues I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP reflection to inspect the class. For example

```
<?php
class Foo {
    public $foo  = 1;
    public $bar  = 2;
}

$foo = new Foo();

$reflect = new ReflectionClass($foo);
$props   = $reflect->getProperties();

foreach ($props as $prop) {
    print "Property Name: " . $prop->getName() . "\n";
    print "Property Value: " . $prop->getValue($foo) . "\n";
}
```

Iterating directories for files you can use [glob](http://php.net/glob)

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, however the php files to be inspected arent classes , they just contain procedural php code.

Comment: IMO, for meta programming, you have to follow some standards i.e. object oriented paradigm. So transform your procedural code to oo and then use the REFLECTION's rich features.